# Disable rule in sonar

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

I want to disable a rule from Sonar so it doesn't show the results in the web page.
In my case I want to hide (or not capture) the results about trailing comments.

Is it posible to configure it somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to remove this rule in the quality profile that you are using to analyse your project.

Please refer to the documentation that describes all this: [Quality Profiles in Sonar](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/).

Comment: where is this quality profile?on localhost:9000,i am getting a profile and rules list but no option for disable a rule.

Comment: @Ankit you need to login to see the Deactivation button

Comment: how to disable those from .net project.  I want to add that rule in dotsettings file. i have added rules which i dont want in dotsettings file. can you please help?

Answer (score 48):

The right way to do is to put something like this on `sonar-project.properties` file per project:

```
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1,e2
# tab characters should not be used
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=squid:S00105
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/*.java
# right curly braces should be on a new line
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=squid:RightCurlyBraceStartLineCheck
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=**/*.java
```

There [are docs here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) on how to ignore specific rules for specific files, which [links to an example of how to search for specific rules, by language](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/sonarsource/rules?languages=java&q=java%3AS1488). This [page on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/sonar-exclude-violations) goes into additional detail better than the docs

Comment: Where can you find documentation about this?

Comment: In my project I had to add the configuration to `pom.xml` instead of creating a new `sonar-project.properties` file. Instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825470/1079869

Comment: What does e1,e2 refer to? I can't find anywhere in docs about what they are used for

Comment: @MaxDoung e1 and e2 don't refer to anything in the Sonar docs. They are keys used within the `sonar-project.properties` file to name the ignore rules. Any names can be chosen, as long as the file is consistent with itself.

Comment: Sonar discourages using this configuration btw, https://community.sonarsource.com/t/documentation-about-ignore-issues-seems-to-be-wrong-or-outdated/3353/2

"We recommend users to use the UI to configure this, for best experience. Consider the configuration via sonar-project.properties as an undocumented hack, not official supported that may or may not work reliably, use at your own risk."

Comment: See the **Ignore Issues** section here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-3

Comment: Also here there is a good article about disabling rules: https://www.baeldung.com/sonar-exclude-violations#2-how-to-get-the-identifier

Answer (score 8):

In web interface for particular rule just press `Deactivate` button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Vladmir's answer in a new answer as I am not able to comment.
You can not modify the built-in profiles. If you don't see the option of Deactivate, then copy the profile and set it as default. Now you will see the options to activate/deactivate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An additional note for people ending up on this thread. I tested this quite a lot and finally found that setting common rules (anything that starts with "common-xxxx") from scanner side (pom, command line etc) will be ignored and it wont work. The language specific rules can be passed line arguments and thats why the "squid:S00105" rule is getting ignored correctly. Here is the issue link on the SonarQube JIRA board and it says that it "wont be fixed".

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8230

Here is the link to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570763/1766402
on how to set it from UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deactivate sonar way rules in a built-in profile. so you have to create your own profile by going to the Quality Profile section and choosing your desired language then click on the config icon the select copy with your favorite name and then you can change any rules in that

[image: here]

and then you can deactivate your considered rules

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

For Java, You can get sonarlint/sonarqube to ignore false-positives by just commenting //NOSONAR at the end of your code statement. As mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128195/sonarqube-incorrectly-reports-preparedstatement-has-no-parameters/73829229#73829229)