# How to disable Sonar rules for specific files?

Tags: sonarqube

I've got a project I'm working on and some of the files violate some of the rules, but in ways that are not real issues, and are thus distracting noise. However, I don't want to disable these rules globally, and I would prefer not to have to mark 'em as false positives one by one.

Is there a way to disable Sonar rules for specific files, and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable rule in sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399311/disable-rule-in-sonar)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since SonarQube 4.0, you can define [issue exclusion patterns](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-5) based on rule key and file path pattern.

On previous versions, you can rely upon the [Switch Off Violations plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/JQAW).

Comment: Great, thanks. A note for future folks that land on this page: the rule key pattern is <repository>:<key>

Comment: @mith The link is broken. Please make your answer self contained.

Comment: http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/JQAW doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

You can annotate a class or a method with SuppressWarnings.

Here is an example:

@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S00111")
squid:S00111 in this case is a Sonar issue ID. You can find this issue id from the Sonar web ui.

Answer (score 11):

You can set specific files and rules under **sonar-project.properties** with following contents:

```
# Ignore Issues
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1,e2
# Skip Bold Check
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=Web:BoldCheck
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/*.html
# Skip Tag Check
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=Web:S1234
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=**/*.html
```

Change the **ruleKey** and **resourceKey** based on your specific need.

Comment: Hello, where can I find "ruleKey" id?

Answer (score 10):

Building on Mithfindel's answer and dpk's comment, this removes the warning

> System.out and System.err should not be used as loggers

from all classes in packages named `log` (or any subpackage thereof) by adding an ignore pattern for the rule `squid:S106`:

[image]

For a list of the keys to all your rules go to your profile under <kbd>Quality Profiles</kbd> and select <kbd>Download</kbd> to get a .csv file containing all the rules' keys.

I'm using SonarQube version 4.1.1.

Comment: I have a Console project and want to disable the rule "Console logging should not be used" on it. I use the UI as you said but it seems MSBuild don't get theses exclusions (anything found in Agent logs, or .sonarqube logs). do I have to have a configuration file or MSbuild should retreive Sonar configuration for projects ? 

Rule Key Pattern:csharpsquid:S2228

File Path Pattern:**/ChangeLog/**/*.*

Comment: BonOeil, you should probably ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 7):

Using below annotation we can ignore the rule from the specific files

For one rule

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S2696")
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {....
```

For more than one rule

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings({"squid:S2696", "squid:S1172", "squid:CommentedOutCodeLine"})
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {...
```

Comment: Just a tip: If you want to get the exact code to put in @SuppressWarning, you can go to the SonarQube Dashboard, and then click into the literal "Why is this an issue?" you're interested on, and a small window will open down the screen; look the right side and you'll see something like "java:S1234". That's code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

- 1.Goto Administration tab->Analysis Scope->Issues
- 2.There , you will find "Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria".
- 3.Provide Rule ID in "Rule Key pattern" textbox [Rule ID can be found by clicking on the particular rule and find it in top right corner]
- 4.Provide Filepath for which you need to ignore rule in "File Path Pattern"  textbox
- 5.Click on Save Issues settings
- [Image to know where Rule ID will be present in the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMJyF.png)
- [Image where Rule key pattern and File Key pattern text boxes are present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyJC.png)