# How to disable SonarLint for test projects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, sonarlint

I installed SonarLint in VS 2015 and it looks like a great extension with lots of potential.

At the moment the extension is also analysing my test projects and giving warnings about this. How can I disable inspection of specific (test) projects?

**Update**
Its not about disabling specific Sonar rules or projects in SonarQube, but its about the Visual Studio extension SonarLint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Sonar rules for specific files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103175/how-to-disable-sonar-rules-for-specific-files)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is not about disabling the rule on the SonarQube server, but inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Our goal is to have a default ruleset applicable for both test and non-tests projects. Could you mention which rules in particular are bothering you on test projects and why?

Comment: @Dinesh, I will have a look tonight which rules. Im not interested in. Probably its mainly about naming and spelling, localization and unused locals

Comment: I let you check - C# naming convention rules should not be available in SonarQube because they cannot be customized (whereas they can in the C# SonarQube plugin). I don't think we have localization rules. Finally, I don't see why you would allow unused locals in tests? In any case, FxCop & other tools rulesets can be changed as described in the answer below.

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam in the case you have a class with a constructor that throws Exception on invalid arguments then you do something like `var testObj = new MyObject()` and then decorate the method with `[ExpectedException(typeof(XxxException))]`. In that case you get that unused local variable warning that I don't care about

Comment: `_ = testObj;` is the simplest way I found for these

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, open the project and then dig into the Reference section. There choose to edit the active rule set:

[image: Open Active Ruleset]

In the screen that opens select/deselect the rules you want for the specific project. Then hit save. This will most likely create a new `.ruleset` file in your project and instruct Roslyn to use that instead of the standard set.

The result is that the project file is updated with the `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` tag like this:

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>UnitTests.Core.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

You can also use the add new file wizard and pick the "Code Analysis Rule set" option:

[image]

Then from the Analyze menu select "Configure Code Analysis for Solution", your newly added rule set can be selected from there and assigned to the project you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this seems to solve my issue.