# Why does sonar try to scan some system files and how to forbid that ?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to use sonar for my project, I've launched scanning, but it was failed and I saw a few errors:

```
error   17-Jul-2018 18:44:45    18:44:45.846 WARN: [/home/myuser/server/RequestHandler.h:5]: cannot find the sources for '#include <string>'
error   17-Jul-2018 18:44:45    18:44:45.847 WARN: [/home/myuser/server/RequestHandler.h:6]: cannot find the sources for '#include <iostream>'
error   17-Jul-2018 18:44:45    18:44:45.847 WARN: [/home/myuser/server/RequestHandler.h:7]: cannot find the sources for '#include <algorithm>'
error   17-Jul-2018 18:44:45    18:44:45.847 WARN: [/home/myuser/server/RequestHandler.h:8]: cannot find the sources for '#include <memory>'
```

RequestHandler.h - this is my file, which includes some std libs, but I don't need to scan system files
How to specify sonar, that I want to scan only files in directory server, and do not touch system libs ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21103175/1531971 and https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles and so on.

Answer (score 0):

please check following properties

```
  sonar.sources=./    #analysis directory    
  sonar.projectBaseDir=./    #Working dir
  sonar.exclusions=**/test/** # exclusions if you have any.
```