# Configure Sonar sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria through maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm using a local instance of Sonar without a centralized infrastructure. In order to keep the configuration of my project in the pom.xml, I want to configure the project through maven and not through the Sonar UI. For me this has the advantage of keeping things in one place and other developers don't have to configure their local Sonar instance, just unpack and play.

The doc on howto configure the `sonar.exclusions` property through maven is readily available but the format for `sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria` is unclear.

How can you configure `sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria` through maven?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After stepping through the code the format is:

```
<properties>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1,e2</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>squid:S00100</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>**/*Steps.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey>squid:S1118</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey>**/PropertyPlaceholderConfig.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey>
</properties>
```

The keys e1,e2 can be chosen arbitrarily as long as they are used with .ruleKey and .resourceKey in the depending properties.

The same works for sonar.issue.ignore.block:

```
 <sonar.issue.ignore.block>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.block>
 <sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>@SonarIgnore</sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>
 <sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp></sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp>
```

Comment: Probably a typo. I removed it. Sonarqube does not seem to accept more than one path there.

Comment: did you intentionally leave the `endBlockRegexp` part empty?

Comment: It looks like `sonar.exclusions` doesn't exclude the multiple paths like `**/enums/**,**/entity/**,**/constant/**`

Comment: Please check this answer out, the above answer won’t work for common rules. Hope that helps someone.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570763/1766402

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the sonar warnings from the sonar.gradle file for the android project.

Add this property on sonar.gradle file.

```
   property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria","e1"
    property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey","xml:S5604"
    property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey","**/AndroidManifest.xml"
```

This is mainly for the android read and write permission security hotspots on sonarqube server.

Make sure path is perfect otherwise it would not work.
Prefer this link for path.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/