# How to Suppress Warnings in Sonar for properties file?

Tags: sonarqube, properties-file

Is it possible to Suppress Warnings in properties file?
Warnings are generated by [SonarQube Java Properties Plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-jproperties-plugin).

Warning key *jproperties:** is (for example *jproperties:key-naming-convention*)

I tried to add comment with

```
#@SuppressWarnings("jproperties:key-naming-convention")
```

Before offending line but it does not work.

I know I could do one of

1. disable those rules in my quality profile
2. suppress warning in Sonar Web UI

I do not want solution 1) because it will ignore rule for all files, not just for single place.

I do not like solution 2) because I have separate sonar project for each branch (master, develop, feature branches) and separate project for each developer (for ad-hoc analysis). I do not want to suppress warnings in webUI for each project separately, I prefer to suppress warnings once-in source code.

Comment: For android project you can do this from the sonar.gradle file as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71553489/6209105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible and there's no plan to add such a feature.
The only thing that you might want to do is to exclude this rule for this very specific file by setting exclusions: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues (Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria criterion)