# Refactor the code not to use Absolute Paths or URIs

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My C# WIndows Forms Application has some menu links which point out to web URIs. But now my SonarQube Scan is giving me this error/warning(S1075) to refactor my code. So what would be the safe/best way to use web URI inside C# backend code.

```
private void HelpDocMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://docs.google.com/document/d/142SFA/edit?usp=sharing");
}
```

SonarQube Error

```
S1075 Refactor your code not to use hardcoded absolute paths or URIs
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can please help me to understand that. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Just ignore it if you do not think it's an issue. AFAIK you can't disable warnings on per line/method basis (at least when i tried out sonarqube) so ignore it or disable it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34041849) answer).

Comment: Which warning? Is there a message or an ID?

Comment: S1075 is the code.

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking the same. I was unable to find any workaround for this. Suppressing this error would be the way to go.

Comment: Hi Everyone. This question got closed due to lack of clarity. I have edited the question. If anyone feels it's clear please reopen the question as I am unable to post any more questions due to this matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three options:

1. To ignore it:

```
private void HelpDocMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   #pragma warning disable S1075 // URIs should not be hardcoded    
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://docs.google.com/document/d/142SFA/edit?usp=sharing");
   #pragma warning restore S1075 // URIs should not be hardcoded
}
```

2. To have a temporary variable like this:

```
private void HelpDocMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/142SFA/edit?usp=sharing";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
}
```

3. To put it in your configuration file, some settings.json.

Third option is the recommended one.