# How to disable sonarqube security hotspot using gradle property?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want to disable or ignore my security check from Sonar Qube for a particular code.
Below the screenshot, I have used directly my entity class in the request body. And I want to keep this change.

Just want to know how do I ignore this using the Sonar Qube Gradle property

```
   sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.exclusions", "abc.java")
        property("sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "./test_results.exec")
        property("sonar.projectKey", "test");
        property("sonar.login", "78t87324jhjahdsgjjhsa")
        property("sonar.host.url", "https://sonarqube.test.te")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For android project you can do this from the sonar.gradle file as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71553489/6209105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress specific warnings by using `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S00XX")` where S00XX is a Sonar issue ID. You can find this ID in the Sonar UI based on your error or warning.

For suppressing multiple warnings you can try like
`@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S00X1", "squid:S00X2"})` i.e. provide multiple Sonar issue IDs.

Or you can also use `//NOSONAR` comment that tells SonarQube to ignore all errors for a specific line.