# sonarqube incorrectly reports "PreparedStatement has no parameters."

Tags: java, sonarqube

**sonarqube** ***incorrectly reports*** on the following (simplified) source `PreparedStatement has no parameters.` (squid:S2695):

```
public static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE TABLE SET COL1=? WHERE PK=?";

private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public void updateMethod(Date date, Long pk )
{
  if(preparedStatement == null)
  {
    //ConnectionService is not a Connection!
    preparedStatement = ConnectionService.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY);
  }

  //sonarqube reports on the following two lines: 'This "PreparedStatement" has no parameters.'
  preparedStatement.setDate(1, date);
  preparedStatement.setLong(2, pk);
  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement .executeQuery(); 

  //further code left out
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a bug or a limitation of the analyser?
2. Is there something I can do to hide these "false positives"?

Comment: Which version of the sonar java analyzer are you using ?

Comment: @benzonico I'm using 3.9

Comment: Don't try to cache `PreparedStatements` like this. If it can be done, the driver will already do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a false positive as you can see [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2036) it's fixed in version 4.5.

**Answer to question 1:**
Yes, it is a bug, upgrade your Sonar version to 4.5 (or newer)
**Answer to question 2:**
*Disable rule in sonar* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399311/disable-rule-in-sonar)
or
*How to remove False-Positive issues?* [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can get sonarlint/sonarqube to ignore false-positives by just commenting *//NOSONAR* at the end of your code line.

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, date); //NOSONAR
preparedStatement.setLong(2, pk); //NOSONAR
```