# Ignore Sonar CSS rule

Tags: css, sonarqube, angular7, sonarqube-scan

I am running `Sonarqube` scan on my *angular 7* application and i see that Sonar report is complaining "**Unexpected unknown pseudo-element selector "::ng-deep"**", does any one know how to mark this rule as ignore or remove this rule.

I tried using `//NOSONAR` , but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable rule in sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399311/disable-rule-in-sonar)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel kind of, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-css/issues/196) sonar-css issue?

Comment: JeroenHeier, yes you are right , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new quality profile and add rules you want and apply on the project.
or exclude that rule from current applied quality profile

Comment: this worked for me. "You need to do it in SonarQube UI. Go to Rules tab, find this rule and edit parameter value for the profile you use for your project(s)."

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube does not allow us to edit the root profile so need to create copy of the same.Once a copy of same profile being created then can deactivate the desired rule.
Imp point to note in order the sonarqube picks the copied version make it default.

To create a copy of rule:-

Quality Profiles > select the profile > right click on setting icons > select copy option from dropdown > edit the copied version > make it default